# Run clang-format in org source block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, c++, formatting, clang-format

I have some org files with cpp source blocks. I want to format the code in the source blocks using `clang-format`. Consider this complete org file:

```
This is a test:

#+begin_src cpp
    
    struct Foo
    {
        void bar() {}
    };
    
#+end_src
```

I place point at the beginning of the line `struct Foo`, hit `C-SPC` (set and activate mark), then move point to the empty line before `#+end_src`. If I now run `clang-format-region`, I get this result:

```
This is a test :

#+begin_src cpp

    struct Foo
{
    void
    bar()
    {}
};

#+end_src
```

Note that the colon after `This is a test` has moved. Somehow, `clang-format` does not only also reformat stuff outside of the region, but also does interpret text outside of the source block as C++ source - which also screws up the formatting inside the source blocks.

Is there a way of properly running `clang-format` only on the contents of a source block?

Comment: Try `C-c '`, then running `clang-format` in the resulting buffer, then `C-c '` to get back to the Org mode buffer - untested.

Comment: Ah yes, that works, thanks. And it should be possible to automate that.